# AndroidManifest file version changes not being recognised

Tags: android, cordova, google-play

Last year I successfully uploaded my first app (alpha version 1) to the playstore. I now want to upload a new version but keep getting the message "You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1".
There are plenty of posts about this problem and they all refer to checking the 'androidmanifest.xml' file. This I have done, and find 4 copies of the file in the following folders:

```
- project\platforms\android
- project\platforms\android\bin
- project\platforms\android\cordovalib
- project\platforms\android\cordovalib\bin
```

There are also two copies of a file 'androidmanifest.cordova.xml' in

```
- project\platforms\android\ant-build
- project\platforms\android\cordovalib\ant-build
```

Now, all six of these files have the correct version definitions:

```
android:versionCode="901" android:versionName="0.9.1"
```

so, why does the playstore console keep telling me it's still version 1?
I have even found all other copies of these files (in other projects on my drive) and none of them have a version 1, except for template files in the \users\chris.cordova folder which is where cordova is installed

Comment: which IDE are you using? Eclipse, or Android Studio in combination with gradle

Comment: Neither Eclipse nor AndroidStudio; neither ideal for Cordova projects (unless they've changed since I last tried). I'm using VS2015 for editing and debugging, then Cordova CLI for building the apk etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by re-installing the Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

You should find a file 'AndroidManifest.xml' on your project path.
It should looks like this one:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.your.package"
android:versionCode="1" <!-- This is the value you have to change -->
android:versionName="1.0.3" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

The versionCode is what you should change from "1" to "2"

Comment: You haven't read my post, I have six files 'AndroidManifest.xml' and none of them have versionCode="1"